# nsp shows a vulnerability which doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, security, express, npm

When I run [`nsp check`](https://github.com/nodesecurity/nsp) against the root of an express application I am making I get this output:

```
(+) 4 vulnerabilities found
┌───────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│               │ Sanitization bypass using HTML Entities             │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Name          │ marked                                              │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Installed     │ 0.2.10                                              │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Vulnerable    │ <=0.3.5                                             │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched       │ >=0.3.6                                             │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ myapp@1.0.0 > marked-engine@0.1.0 > marked@0.2.1    │
├───────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More Info     │ https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/101              │

... 3 more omitted, all concerning marked@0.2.10
```

even though the version of `marked` I am using is `0.3.6`:

```
$ npm list
myapp@1.0.0
├── ...
└─┬ marked-engine@0.1.0
  └── marked@0.3.6
```

So, what's the problem? Why does `nsp` report this vulnerability?

Comment: `marked-engine@0.1.0` _does_ [declare `marked@0.2.x`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/marked-engine/blob/192c260eae33964cfc0c062b5e0fbb19e5efb5e3/package.json#L20) as a dependency, so my guess would be that `nsp` only checks _declared_ dependencies and not _installed_ dependencies.